# how to search with hashtags using sunspot gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I'm building a twitter-like rails app using rails 4 with [sunspot](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot) gem.

I want it to be able to search with hashtags.

For example, if there are two tweets:

1. Harry Potter is a great book
2. Harry Potter is a great `#book`

the search term `#book` will only return the second tweet instead of both of them (which is what I get now).

and if I search `book`, it should return both of them.

`sunspot_solr` seems to escape the `#` sign, that's why I can't get what I want.

So my question is, how do I implement this feature?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to treat `#book` specially.

Extracting `#book` from the content before save the new `tweet` to database, `find_or_create` a `tag` object, create a many-to-many relationship between tweets and tags, thereafter save them to database.

when searching with hashtags, only search in the related tags.